# Embedding Python in a CPP Project

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, scripting, game-engine

I am making a game engine in cpp and I want to add python scripting support. I want the python script to be able to access classes from my cpp API and cpp to be able to call functions on the script for example Update(Delta time) every frame. Im using Visual Studio 2017. The cpp should be the host of the python code.

How should I interface with a python VM in my cpp VS2017 project ?
How should I give the script access to cpp classes ?

To clarify:

This is not a debugging question it's a design question.

It's important to me to have full control of the python environment.

This is not a python project extended with CPP performance code.
It should be a native unmanaged cpp project extended with python scripting support.

Comment: Might be worth looking into [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @Shawn never heard of this one. Do you think it would be better than pyBind11 or Mono+IronPython for my use case ?

Comment: Beats me; I don't do python, much less mixing it with C++. I just know it's a nicer interface to python for C++ than using the C bindings directly is.

Comment: @Shawn im not a python guy neither

Comment: @Shawn I tried boost.python and I like it , it does what I need. thank you. If you want make an answer so I'll mark the question as solved